# Objective-C - Strange getter methods

Tags: objective-c, getter

For my property `HomeButton*sharedHomeButtonInstance`, when I type `-getshared...` in Xcode, it suggests this to me

```
- (void)getSharedHomeButtonInstance:(HomeButton **)buffer range:(NSRange)inRange {

}
```

Why does the getter method need a buffer and range, and what are they?

Comment: Getters typically don't start with 'get' so I suspect it's some custom method.  Try typing `shared...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The getter method you want is:

```
- (HomeButton *)sharedHomeButtonInstance
{
    return ...;
}
```